# TextEdit indent with numbers

Tags: textedit, indent

To indent a paragraph in TextEdit I found that I can go to **Format > Text > Show Ruler** and then drag the indent. The problem is that it is very difficult to give a exact number, for instance 1cm.

Is there a better way to select only some specific paragraphs and apply the same exact indent always?

Comment: Is this an OS X question?

Comment: Seems like the answer here is going to be suggestive. My first thought would be to try a better editor.